# Push to repo from another repo

Tags: git, gitlab

I cloned a project (some other project).

I cloned another empty project. I want to put all of the code from the other project into mine.

How do I do that?

Comment: clone the project inside the other project file

Comment: Copy the files? Do you want to maintain it as nested projects?

Comment: BTW your question/topic and description dsnt match at all

Comment: @DaveNewton copying the files is what I could do. I was overcomplicating things. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

A way to do this would be to just download the .zip file of the repo that you want to download, then just extract it and import it into your own project by dragging in the files. This is assuming you are using the website and not the CLI.

Answer (score 0):

You can delete the `.git` folder of the project that you want to copy. It will remove all git related log and files. Then you can run `git init` to initialize a brand new Git repository with all the existing files.